# Proof that for 2 integers of which their product is 1, then each integer is 1.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I am working through my Real Analysis' exercises and have run into one that conceptually is very straight forward but has proven to be somewhat difficult for me. I suppose it is less "Real Analysis" and more just learning to create proofs.

The claim is:
$$\forall p,q\in \mathbb{Z} \:(p>0 \wedge q>0 \wedge pq=1) \implies p=q=1$$

Now my issue is that I'm not really sure what it is appropriate to assume in this circumstance, as I suppose the goal is being able to prove it in the most fundamental way possible.
For example, we know for most elements in the integers, they do not possess a multiplicative inverse, except for 1 and -1. If we applied this, the proof would be pretty easy, but I would say we would be able to extend the proof of our claim to prove this fact itself.

Here's my attempt at a proof:
$$
Assume \:p,q\in\mathbb{Z} \: such \: that \: pq=1 \; and \; p>0 \; and \; q>0
\\Assume  \: for \; a\;contradiction \;that\;p\neq1 \; or \; q\neq1 \; or \; p\neq1 \; and\; q\neq1 
\\Then \; 1=|pq|=|p||q|\geq |p| \; and\; 1=|pq|=|p||q|\geq |q|
\\ Then \; 1\geq p\; and \; 1\geq q
\\ p=1 \; or \; p=0 \; and \; q=1\; or\; q=0
\\ But \; this \; is \; a \; contradiction \; as \; p>0\; and \; q>0\; and\; both\; p,q\; cannot \; simultaneously \; be\; 0.
\\ Hence \; \forall p,q\in \mathbb{Z} \:(p>0 \wedge q>0 \wedge pq=1) \implies p=q=1 \; $$

(Sorry can't figure out the QED symbol in LaTeX, clearly not very good at it).

Is this proof solid or would there be a more fundamental method of reaching the conclusion.

Also, would anyone have any good resources that assisted them in really grasping Real Analysis and Proofs in general?

Thanks!

Comment: Using the norm does not seem fundamental for me. Using group axioms would be much more fundamental. So I would use the fact that $1,-1$ are the only units of $\mathbb{Z}$. I don't see, why you have to make it that complicated

Comment: Taking aboslute value certainly works. Suppose that $pq=1$ in $\Bbb Z$. Then $1=|pq|=|p|\cdot |q|$. If either $|p|>1$ or $|q|>1$, we immediately have a contradiction. This is exactly how to prove that the unit group is $U(\Bbb Z)=\{\pm 1\}$.

Comment: If $1=pq$ then both $p$ and $q$ are divisors of the unit. _There are just two_ in $\mathbb Z$, and only one of them is positive. I do not know, however, if the italicized part is elementary enough to be used here...

Comment: Latex comment: use \textnormal{ 'insert text' } or \text{ 'insert text' } when you want to type words inside of a math environment

Comment: To add some info @CSquared gave, the QED symbol can be `\square` or `\blacksquare`.

Comment: Regarding your last question, reading Rudin's analysis (or really any analysis book, Rudin is just my personal favorite) and taking an analysis/proof based course were the things that helped me improve. But just keep finding problems to solve and stick with them. Even if you have to look at the solution, it helps you understand how you're supposed to think while writing a proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Comments:**

You never actually use the hypothesis that $p,q\neq 1$ and you're argument doesn't require the use of absolute value signs, since by hypothesis, we have $p,q>0$. Besides, if you start off with the assumption that $p,q\neq 1$ and $p,q>0$, then you should conclude that $p,q\geq 2$. The contradiction you should have reached is $1\geq 2$, which actually utilizes the additional assumption that $p,q\neq 1$ and would make for a sound proof by contradiction.

**Alternative Solution (1):**

To be more general however, lets just say $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ and suppose we have $pq=1$. Aiming for a more direct approach, we notice that if one of $p$ or $q$ were $0$, then we would have $pq=0\neq 1$, so we can assume $p,q\neq 0$. Now, $|p|,|q|\geq 1$, since $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$. From your argument, we have $$1=|pq|=|p||q|\geq |p|\geq 1\text{ and }1=|pq|=|p||q|\geq |q|\geq 1 $$
so we must have $|p|=|q|=1$.

Now we can immediately check off the four cases that satisfy the previous relation, those being $$p=1,q=1\tag{1}$$ $$p=-1,q=-1\tag{2}$$ $$p=1, q=-1\tag{3}$$ $$p=-1,q=1\tag{4}$$
and conclude that we must have either case $(1)$ or case $(2)$. The cases come directly from the definition of $|\cdot|:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, that being $|x|=\max\{x,-x\}$.

In fact, once you have $|p|=1$, then you can conclude that $p=1$ or $p=-1$ so that $1=q$ or $1=-q$.

**Alternative Solution (2):**

Let that $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $p,q>0$ and $pq=1$. We immediately see that $p,q\geq 1$. Assume for contradiction that  $p$ or $q$ is larger than $1$. Without loss of generality, suppose $p > 1$. Write $p$ in terms of its prime factors:
$$p=p_1^{k_1}\cdot p_2^{k_2}\cdots p_n^{k_n}$$

We must have $p_1\geq 2$ since $p_1$ is a positive prime, hence $$1=pq\geq p_1q\geq 2\cdot 1=2$$ a contradiction. Our assumption that $p$ or $q$ was greater than one must be false, hence $p=q=1$.

**Alternative Solution (3):**

Let $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $p,q>0$ and $pq=1$. Then $p,q\geq 1$ $\ln(p),\ln(q)\geq\ln(1)=0$. Now we see that $$0=\ln(1)=\ln(pq)=\ln(p)+\ln(q)\geq\ln(p)\geq 0$$
hence $\ln(p)=\ln(1)=0$. Since $\ln$ is injective, then we must have $p=1$. Now $1=pq=q$ so $q=1$.

**Alternative Solution (4):**

Assuming the same hypothesis as the first solution, we have that $p\mid q$ and $q\mid p$, so there exists non-zero integers $t_1,t_2$ such that $$p=t_1q\text{ and }q=t_2p$$Now, $$t_1q^2=1=t_2p^2$$ and we conclude that because $q^2,p^2>0$, then we must have $t_1,t_2>0$, or equivalently $t_1,t_2\geq 1$. But we also see that if $t_1,t_2>1$, then so are $t_1q^2$ and $t_2p^2$, hence $t_1=t_2=1$. Now we see that $pq=p^2=q^2=1$. Since the only solutions to the polynomial $f(x)=x^2-1$ are $x=\pm 1$, then the result follows.

**Alternative Solution (5):**

Let $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $pq=1$. Consider matricies
$$R
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 && -p\\
q && 1
\end{bmatrix} 
,\,\,\,
R^{-1}
=
\frac{1}{1-(-pq)}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 && p\\
-q && 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then $RR^{-1}=I$ so we have
$$RR^{-1}=
\frac{1}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
2 && p-q\\
0 && 2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 && 0\\
0 && 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
Now we must have $p=q$, implying $p^2-1=0$ and the result follows.

**Final Comment:**

It would be cool to see a proof done using group or ring theory to show this result as well. I cannot fully see through a proof by those means as of right now, but I believe its likely that it can be done.